# Parallel solving in Z3

Tags: c++, z3

One of the new features in Z3 4.8.1 is parallel solving:

> A parallel mode is available for select theories, including QF_BV. By
>   setting parallel.enable=true Z3 will spawn a number of worker threads
>   proportional to the number of available CPU cores to apply cube and
>   conquer solving on the goal.

It mentions that just `parallel.enable=true` needs to be set but I can't find that `parallel` structure in the code.

Can someone provide some example code to see how to implement this new feature?

Thank you

Comment: http://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-parallel-z3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** As @LeventErkok points out, the syntax of `parallel.enable=true` is for use in the command line to the z3 executable itself.  And as he says and [@Claies's link had indicated](http://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-parallel-z3), if you are using a binding, you will want to use the relevant `set_param()` method.  For C++ that is `set_param("parallel.enable", true);`

When I added this to the 
[C++ binding example](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/a0007476051943b04034880516a36278f117929e/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp), it gave basically the same output...though it spat out some extra information to stderr, a bunch of lines like:

```
(tactic.parallel :progress 0% :closed 0 :open 1)
(tactic.parallel :progress 100% :status sat :closed 0 :open 0)
```

Which matches @LeventErkrok's observed difference using the z3 tool on another problem.

---

> It mentions that just parallel.enable=true needs to be set but I can't find that parallel structure in the code.

*(I was curious what Z3 was all about, so I also went looking in the C++ sources for parallel.enable.  So that's where my answer started out from, before people who knew more answered.  My findings left here for anyone interested...)*

**Long answer:** If you're looking through the sources for z3 itself, you won't find a C++ object called `parallel` where you'd write `parallel.enable = true;`.  It's a property stored in a configuration object managed by string names.  That configuration object is called `parallel_params`, it's not in GitHub because it is generated as part of the build process, into `src/solver/parallel_params.hpp`

The specification for these properties and their defaults is per-module in a `.pyg` file.  This is just Python which is loaded by the build preparation process and [eval()'d with a few things defined](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/520ce9a5ee6079651580b6d83bc2db0f342b8a20/scripts/mk_genfile_common.py#L928).  The parallel solver options are in [`src/solver/parallel_params.pyg`](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/12fc6708395f4e563ffbf8e0d2863bcf2ffd6538/src/solver/parallel_params.pyg#L6), e.g.:

```
def_module_params('parallel',
    description='parameters for parallel solver',
    class_name='parallel_params',
    export=True,
    params=(
        ('enable', BOOL, False, 'enable parallel solver ...'),
        ('threads.max', UINT, 10000, 'caps maximal number of threads ...'),
        # ...etc.
```

If you want to change these defaults while building z3, it looks like you have to edit the `.pyg` file, as there seems no parameterization for something like `python scripts/mk_make.py parallel.enable=true`.

As an example of how changing this file affects the generated header defining the parallel properties, I directly modified `parallel_params.pyg` to say "True" instead of "False" for its default.  The consequence was the following 2-line diff to the generated `src/solver/parallel_params.hpp` file:

```
-- a/src/solver/parallel_params.hpp
+++ b/src/solver/parallel_params.hpp
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@ struct parallel_params {
   parallel_params(params_ref const & _p = params_ref::get_empty()):
      p(_p), g(gparams::get_module("parallel")) {}
   static void collect_param_descrs(param_descrs & d) {
-    d.insert("enable", CPK_BOOL, "enable parallel solver by default on selected tactics (for QF_BV)", "false","parallel");
+    d.insert("enable", CPK_BOOL, "enable parallel solver by default on selected tactics (for QF_BV)", "true","parallel");
     d.insert("threads.max", CPK_UINT, "caps maximal number of threads below the number of processors", "10000","parallel");
     d.insert("conquer.batch_size", CPK_UINT, "number of cubes to batch together for fast conquer", "100","parallel");
     d.insert("conquer.restart.max", CPK_UINT, "maximal number of restarts during conquer phase", "5","parallel");
@@ -23,7 +23,7 @@ struct parallel_params {
      REG_MODULE_PARAMS('parallel', 'parallel_params::collect_param_descrs')
      REG_MODULE_DESCRIPTION('parallel', 'parameters for parallel solver')
   */
-  bool enable() const { return p.get_bool("enable", g, false); }
+  bool enable() const { return p.get_bool("enable", g, true); }
   unsigned threads_max() const { return p.get_uint("threads.max", g, 10000u); }
   unsigned conquer_batch_size() const { return p.get_uint("conquer.batch_size", g, 100u); }
   unsigned conquer_restart_max() const { return p.get_uint("conquer.restart.max", g, 5u); }
```

Comment: And for enabling parallel mode in the official python binding from pip?

Comment: @user2284570 Just glancing at it, it looks like there is a [set_param](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a54767807c828563030b9400332f81d48) exposed there as well.  I'd gather the syntax from the comments in that file would be `solver.set_param(parallel_enable=True)`, but the other answer suggests `set_param('parallel.enable', True)`...so YMMV.

Comment: Thank you and how to use more than 1 thread when having this parameter enabled?

Answer (score 6):

## From the command line

If you are using the z3 executable, then you simply pass the setting in the command line. That is, if your script is in file `a.smt2`, use:

```
 z3 parallel.enable=true a.smt2
```

and z3 will use the parallel solver as it processes the benchmark. For instance:

```
$ cat a.smt2
(set-logic QF_AUFBV )
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-fun a () (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-fun b () (_ BitVec 32))
(assert (bvult a b))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Regular call:

```
$ z3 a.smt2
sat
(model
  (define-fun a () (_ BitVec 32)
    #x00000000)
  (define-fun b () (_ BitVec 32)
    #x00000001)
)
```

Parallel mode:

```
$ z3 parallel.enable=true a.smt2
(tactic.parallel :progress 0% :closed 0 :open 1)
(tactic.parallel :progress 100% :status sat :closed 0 :open 0)
sat
(model
  (define-fun a () (_ BitVec 32)
    #x00000000)
  (define-fun b () (_ BitVec 32)
    #x00000001)
)
```

Note the extra comments regarding the execution of the parallel mode in the second run.

## Programmatically

If you're asking about how to use it from the programmatic API? For Python, it would look like:

```
from z3 import *
set_param('parallel.enable', True)
```

I'm sure other API's have similar calls. (Caveat: I haven't actually used/tested this feature myself; and since it's rather new, it might be the case that not all programmatic APIs support it. Hopefully, you get a nice warning/error if that's the case!)

Comment: Thank you, But how to get more than 1 separate thread when this option is enabled?

Comment: There seems to be an example here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/python/parallel.py