# How to run Z3 using multiple cores?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am trying to improve the timing of my Z3 code. I have observed that Z3 always utilizes only one core, no matter how many cores my machine has. Is there a way in which Z3 might be able to use all the cores as it will certainly improve performance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallel solving in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246030/parallel-solving-in-z3)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246030/parallel-solving-in-z3